# Responsive menu items css not stacking together

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, responsive

I've got a small issue with my mobile menu (max-width: 768px), go check on -> https://tvo35400.com/

The issue seems quite simple : I want the 4 menu items to stack together, not to spread accross the whole window.

Here is the code for my nav container :

```
#menu-menu-ville {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #374875;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform: translateX(-20rem);
    z-index: 999999;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

It works partially when I apply `{flex-direction: column;}` but the issue is that the menu scroll is now horizontal rather than vertical.

You can check my jQuery script too, in case you need it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function($) {
     $(".header-icon").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".header-icon").css("opacity", "0");
      $(".logo-wrapper").css("right", "2px");
      $("#menu-menu-ville").css("transform", "translateX(0)");
      $(".overlay").css("visibility", "visible");
      $(".overlay").css("opacity", "0.6");
      $(".main-nav").css("translateX", "20rem");
      $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    });

    $(".overlay").click(function(e) {
      $(".header-icon").css("opacity", "1");
      $(".logo-wrapper").css("right", "15px");
      $("#menu-menu-ville").css("transform", "translateX(-20rem)");
      $(".overlay").css("visibility", "hidden");
      $(".overlay").css("opacity", "0");
      $("body").css("overflow", "initial");

    });

    $(".menu-item-has-children").click(function(e) {
      $(this).find(".sub-menu").slideToggle();

    });  
  });
});
```

In advance, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want something like this:

[image]

add `items:flex-start; align-content:flex-start;` to #menu-menu-ville on mobile veiw

Comment: It's working exactly like I wanted ! Thanks a lot !